# converting nested XML to 3d array

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, xna

```
<players>
    <player>
        <playerName>Guest</playerName>
        <playerID>1</playerID>
        <highScore>0</highScore>
        <levels>
            <level>
                <number>111</number>
                <bestTime>222</bestTime>
                <timesCompleted>333</timesCompleted>
            </level>
            <level>
                <number>112</number>
                <bestTime>113</bestTime>
                <timesCompleted>114</timesCompleted>
            </level>
        </levels>
    </player>
    <player>
        <playerName>Guest2</playerName>
        <playerID>2</playerID>
        <highScore>0</highScore>
        <levels>
            <level>
                <number>111</number>
                <bestTime>221</bestTime>
                <timesCompleted>441</timesCompleted>
            </level>
        </levels>
    </player>
</players>
```

Hi!

So I have the XML structure listed above, and am trying to parse it in C#/XNA so I have the name, ID and highscore in variables, then the level data (bearing in mind there are multiple levels per player) into a list of arrays (for now) that look like:

> [[111,222,333][112,113,114]],[[111,221,441]]

or a 3D jagged array, I guess.

I have the following code so far:

```
double[][] test = xDoc.Root.Elements("player").Elements("levels").Elements("level")
                  .Select(level => level.Elements().Select(x => (double)x).ToArray())
                  .ToArray();
```

But obviously that's a 2D array and that only seems to be giving me the first player's results - but I can't figure out how to generalise it. Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't care which player the levels are for, just want to put all levels from all players into one multi dimensional array?

Comment: no, I want the levels data to be associated with the correct player. Ultimately I will put the information into a List of structs, where the structs are PlayerData, containing the player's name and ID, and the levels they've played and their times for those levels.

Comment: Ok see if my answer does what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces what I believe is the result you want:

```
int[][][] result = xDoc
    .Root
    .Elements("player")
    .Select(p => p
        .Elements("levels")
        .Elements("level")
        .Select(l => l
            .Elements()
            .Select(e => int.Parse(e.Value))
            .ToArray()
        ).ToArray()
    ).ToArray();
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thats great! Thanks so much! Turns out I did get there myself about an hour before I gave in and asked the question here, but I was reading the wrong xml file (!)

Answer (score 3):

This will give you 3D array and traverse all you node

```
  var playersNode = myDocument.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(nodeVariant => nodeVariant.Name == "players").First();
  var levelsNode  =   playersNode.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Select(nodeVariant => nodeVariant.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(nodeVariant1 => nodeVariant1.Name == "levels"));
  double[][][] output = levelsNode.Select(o => o.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Select(o1 => new[] { Convert.ToDouble(o.Attributes["number"]), Convert.ToDouble(o.Attributes["bestTime"]), Convert.ToDouble(o.Attributes["timesCompleted"]) }).ToArray()).ToArray();
```